# Is the variance of the maximum of a set of variables higher than the variance of the other variables?

Tags: variance, extreme-value

Does the maximum of a set of random variables have high variance compared to the other variables in the set? If so, can someone give an intuitive explanation of why?

Some details about the motivation:
I am using a random hash to hash a large set of random integers (large domain) to a much smaller range of integers. I am interested in the maximum number of hash collisions. When I do this multiple times with different random integers and different random seeds in the hash I see there is a very high variance in the maximum number of hash collisions (between 1/2 and 1 times the average maximum number of collisions). I am trying to get an intuition for why this is the case.

Comment: Not without further assumptions. Let $X,Y$ be $\{0,1\}$-valued such that $P(X=1)=P(Y=1)=0.5$ but $X=1-Y$. Then $max(X,Y)=1$ and has variance $0$, but each RV has variance 1/2.

Comment: Generally, when those variables are identically distributed and independent (or nearly so), the answer depends on the upper tail of the distribution.  A long tail can cause the maximum to be extremely variable, whereas a short tail will cause the maximum to be nearly constant.  A uniform or gaussian distribution are good examples of the latter.  The hash collision problem is quite tractable: you can in principle work out the *exact* distribution of the maximum count.  Good approximations are available, too. The answer could depend on what your hashing algorithm is, so please tell us.

Comment: @whuber thanks. Yes it's a bioinformatics application, the details are a bit more complicated but essentially the larger integers are hashed by choosing the minimum fixed length run of bits in the integer and XORing them with a random string of bits of that length